# Rendering OpenGL ES 2.0 to UIImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, image-processing, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I am interested in writing some code which processes an image using OpenGL ES 2.0 and then reads out the image back to memory again (to eventually be saved). I have some other code which does some more complex processing and just renders the image to display which works. I now want some code which runs the same processing but just saves the image. It doesn't need to be rendered to the screen.

I have created a frame buffer object which outputs to a texture. I then want to use glReadPixels to get the contents of the frame buffer back into memory. The following code snippet should just take a UIImage, resize it to fit onto a 512x512 canvas and then write it out as a 512x512 UIImage. I can't seem to get anything meaningful to display though. If I use an image smaller than 512x512 it does seem to render, but it's as if it is drawing straight from the texture storage (because I pad images to always be a power of 2 size). The image displays but if I change any of the drawing code, it doesn't affect it.

I'd really appreciate if you could give me some insight?

Thanks!

Here is my Vertex Shader:

```
attribute vec4 Position;
attribute vec4 SourceColour;

varying vec4 DestinationColour;
uniform vec2 ScreenSize;

attribute vec2 TexCoordIn;
varying vec2 TexCoordOut;

void main(void) {
    DestinationColour = SourceColour;
    vec4 newPosition = Position;
    newPosition.x = Position.x / ScreenSize.x;
    newPosition.y = Position.y / ScreenSize.y;
    gl_Position = Position;
    TexCoordOut = TexCoordIn;
}
```

Here is my fragment shader:

```
varying lowp vec2 TexCoordOut;
uniform sampler2D Texture;

void main(void)
{
    lowp vec4 pixel = texture2D(Texture, TexCoordOut);
    gl_FragColor = pixel;
}
```

Here is the main code body:

```
#import "SERootViewController.h"
#import <OpenGLES/ES2/gl.h>

typedef struct {
    CGSize  size;
    CGPoint percentage;
    GLuint  id;
} Texture;

typedef struct {
    float Position[3];
    float TexCoord[2];
} Vertex;

size_t nextPowerOfTwo(size_t n)
{
    size_t po2 = 2;
    while(po2<n) {
        po2 = po2*2;
    }
    return po2;
}

const GLubyte Indices[] = {
    0, 1, 2,
    2, 3, 0
};

@interface SERootViewController ()
{
    EAGLContext    *_context;

    //OpenGL
    GLuint _vertexBufferHandle;
    GLuint _indexBufferHandle;
    GLuint _vertexShaderHandle;
    GLuint _fragmentShaderHandle;
    GLuint _programHandle;
    GLuint _positionHandle;
    GLuint _texCoordHandle;
    GLuint _textureHandle;
    GLuint _screenSizeHandle;

    GLuint _fbo;
    GLuint _fboTexture;

    Texture _imageTexture;
    GLfloat _defaultScale;

    Vertex  *_vertices;
    CGSize  _screenSize;

    //Cocoa
    UIImageView *_imageView;
}
@end

@implementation SERootViewController

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Lifecycle
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

- (id)init
{
    if ( (self = [super init]) != nil)
    {
        _context = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2];
        _vertices = malloc(sizeof(Vertex) * 4);
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self __setupFrameBuffer];
    [self __setupShaders];
    CGSize size = CGSizeMake(512, 512);
    [self __setScreenSize:size];

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"christmas.jpg"];
    GLubyte *bytes = [self __bytesFromImage:image];
    _imageTexture = [self __newTexture:bytes size:image.size];
    free(bytes);

    [self __setupVBOs:_imageTexture screenSize:size];
    [self __renderTexture:_imageTexture];
    [self __bindFrameBuffer];

    GLubyte *imageBytes = [self __renderImage:size];
    UIImage *newImage = [self __imageFromBytes:imageBytes size:size];
    free(imageBytes);

    _imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    _imageView.image = newImage;
    _imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    [self.view addSubview:_imageView];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Methods
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

- (void)__setScreenSize:(CGSize)screenSize
{
    _screenSize = screenSize;
    glUniform2f(_screenSizeHandle, _screenSize.width, _screenSize.height);
}

- (void)__setupFrameBuffer
{
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &_fbo);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, _fbo);

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glGenTextures(1, &_fboTexture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _fboTexture);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, 512, 512, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, _fboTexture, 0);
}

- (void)__bindFrameBuffer
{
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _fboTexture);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, _fbo);
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, _fboTexture, 0);
}

- (GLuint) __compileShader:(NSString *)shaderStr type:(GLenum) type
{
    const char *str = shaderStr.UTF8String;

    int  shaderStrLength = strlen(str);

    GLuint shaderHandle = glCreateShader(type);

    glShaderSource(shaderHandle, 1, &str, &shaderStrLength);

    glCompileShader(shaderHandle);

    GLint compileSuccess;
    glGetShaderiv(shaderHandle, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &compileSuccess);
    if (compileSuccess == GL_FALSE)
    {
        GLchar messages[512];
        glGetShaderInfoLog(shaderHandle, sizeof(messages), 0, &messages[0]);
        NSLog(@"Shader Error: %s", messages);
    }

    return shaderHandle;
}

- (void)__setupVBOs:(Texture)texture screenSize:(CGSize)screenSize
{
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &_vertexBufferHandle);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &_indexBufferHandle);

    _defaultScale = MIN( (screenSize.height/texture.size.height), (screenSize.width/texture.size.width) );
    GLfloat width = texture.size.width*_defaultScale;
    GLfloat height = texture.size.height*_defaultScale;

    Vertex vertices[] = {{{ width/2,   height/2, 0}, {texture.percentage.x, texture.percentage.y}},
        {{ width/2,  0, 0}, {texture.percentage.x, 0}},
        {{0,  0, 0}, {0, 0}},
        {{0,   height/2, 0}, {0, texture.percentage.y}}
    };

    memcpy(_vertices, vertices, sizeof(vertices));

    glGenBuffers(1, &_vertexBufferHandle);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vertexBufferHandle);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), _vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glGenBuffers(1, &_indexBufferHandle);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, _indexBufferHandle);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Indices), Indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
}

- (void) __setupShaders
{
    NSString *vertexFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"vertexShader" ofType:@"glsl"];
    NSString *vertexShader = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:vertexFilePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

    NSString *fragmentFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"fragmentShader" ofType:@"glsl"];
    NSString *fragmentShader = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:fragmentFilePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

    _vertexShaderHandle = [self __compileShader:vertexShader type:GL_VERTEX_SHADER];
    _fragmentShaderHandle = [self __compileShader:fragmentShader type:GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER];

    _programHandle = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(_programHandle, _vertexShaderHandle);
    glAttachShader(_programHandle, _fragmentShaderHandle);
    glLinkProgram(_programHandle);



    GLint linkSuccess;
    glGetProgramiv(_programHandle, GL_LINK_STATUS, &linkSuccess);

    if (linkSuccess == GL_FALSE)
    {
        GLchar messages[512];
        glGetProgramInfoLog(_programHandle, sizeof(messages), 0, &messages[0]);
        NSLog(@"GLSL ERROR: %s", messages);
    }

    glUseProgram(_programHandle);

    _positionHandle = glGetAttribLocation(_programHandle, "Position");
    _texCoordHandle = glGetAttribLocation(_programHandle, "TexCoordIn");

    _screenSizeHandle = glGetUniformLocation(_programHandle, "ScreenSize");
    _textureHandle = glGetUniformLocation(_programHandle, "Texture");

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(_positionHandle);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(_texCoordHandle);
}

- (Texture)__newTexture:(void *)bytes size:(CGSize)size
{
    Texture texture;

    size_t wpo2 = nextPowerOfTwo(size.width);
    size_t hpo2 = nextPowerOfTwo(size.height);

    texture.size = size;
    texture.percentage = CGPointMake((float)size.width  / (float)wpo2, (float)size.height / (float)hpo2);

    void * texData = (GLubyte *) malloc(wpo2*hpo2*4*sizeof(GLubyte));
    memset(texData, 1, sizeof(GLubyte)*size.width*4);

    for(GLuint i=0;i<size.height;i++)
    {
        memcpy(&texData[wpo2*i*4], &bytes[(int)size.width*i*4], sizeof(GLubyte)*(int)size.width*4);
    }
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
    glGenTextures(1, &texture.id);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture.id);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, (GLsizei)wpo2, (GLsizei)hpo2, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, texData);

    free(texData);

    return texture;
}

-(void) __renderTexture:(Texture) texture
{
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.5, 0.0, 1.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glVertexAttribPointer(_positionHandle, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE,
                          sizeof(Vertex), 0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(_texCoordHandle, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE,
                          sizeof(Vertex), (GLvoid*) (sizeof(float) * 3));

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture.id);
    glUniform1i(_textureHandle, 1);

    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, sizeof(Indices)/sizeof(Indices[0]),GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
}

- (GLubyte *)__renderImage:(CGSize)size
{
    GLubyte *image = malloc(size.width*size.height*4*sizeof(GLubyte));
    glReadPixels(0, 0, size.width, size.height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
    return image;
}

- (GLubyte *)__bytesFromImage:(UIImage *)image
{
    GLint maxTextureSize;
    glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE, &maxTextureSize);
    CGFloat maxSize = MAX(image.size.width, image.size.height);

    CGFloat width = image.size.width;
    CGFloat height = image.size.height;

    if (maxSize > maxTextureSize)
    {
        CGFloat scale = maxTextureSize/maxSize;

        width = roundf(width*scale);
        height = roundf(height*scale);
    }

    CGImageRef spriteImage = image.CGImage;
    if (!spriteImage) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to load image");
        exit(1);
    }

    GLubyte * imgData = (GLubyte *) malloc(width*height*4*sizeof(GLubyte));
    CGContextRef spriteContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(imgData, width, height, 8, width*4,
                                                       CGImageGetColorSpace(spriteImage), (CGBitmapInfo)kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);

    UIGraphicsPushContext(spriteContext);
    CGContextSaveGState(spriteContext);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height)];
    CGContextRestoreGState(spriteContext);
    UIGraphicsPopContext();
    CGContextRelease(spriteContext);

    return imgData;
}

- (UIImage *)__imageFromBytes:(GLubyte *)bytes size:(CGSize)size
{
    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, bytes, (size.width * size.height * 4), NULL);

    // set up for CGImage creation
    int bitsPerComponent = 8;
    int bitsPerPixel = 32;
    int bytesPerRow = 4 * size.width;
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpaceRef = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault;
    CGColorRenderingIntent renderingIntent = kCGRenderingIntentDefault;
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreate(size.width, size.height, bitsPerComponent, bitsPerPixel, bytesPerRow, colorSpaceRef, bitmapInfo, provider, NULL, NO, renderingIntent);
    // make UIImage from CGImage

    UIImage *newUIImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    return newUIImage;
}

@end
```

Comment: Where do you set your glViewport()? Also, why are you binding your framebuffer after you render and not before? That doesn't seem right. Finally, if you don't feel like reinventing the wheel, may I suggest my project here: https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage , which handles OpenGL ES 2.0 image processing for you.

Comment: I do actually use that library on some other projects (it's really great btw). However, I want this code to eventually be cross-platform for iOS and android. My OpenGL is a little rusty, thanks for highlighting these, i'll investigate.